# How to get sum(boolean) as integer in hibernate's criteria query?

Tags: hibernate, criteria

In a simple 'vote up / vote down' scenario , I want to sum the total 'up' count .

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("vote" , Boolean.TRUE));
criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount());
```

The generated SQL is `sum(this_.vote) as y1_`  and generates correct sum value , but hibernate parsed it as 'boolean' value , all become 'true' ...

How to solve it ? ( if I don't need to change the 'vote' from boolean to integer )

environment : hibernate-3.6.0 , jpa2

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What DB are you using? I think you might need to change the dialect with which hibernate is working.

Let hibernate use Tinyint for boolean variables.

Not on my working copmuter atm - sorry. If this might be the right direction get back at me and I will get an example later.

This might help you get started in the meantime: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1008105

cheers

EDIT:

Ok. Since you're using Mysql, you might want to extend an existing MySQL Dialect - e.g. standard MySQL5Dialect:

```
 public class MySQL5DialectBooleanAsTinyint extends MySQL5Dialect {

  public MySQL5DialectBooleanAsTinyint() {
    super();
    registerColumnType(Types.BIT, "tinyint(1)");
  }

}
```

And that's it. To use your Custom Dialect, change your hibernate.cfg accordingly:

```
 <property name="hibernate.dialect">your.package.structure.dao.MySQL5DialectBooleanAsTinyint</property>
```

Comment: Hi , I found another exception . The solution doesn't work for projectionlist.add(Projections.sum("vote") , "sum"); Hibernate still regards the returned int as boolean.

Comment: Types.BIT change that or add Types.BOOLEAN maybe this helps?

Comment: Oops , it still doesn't help.

Comment: To sum up : registerColumnType(Types.BIT, "tinyint(1)") , and registerColumnType(Types.BOOLEAN, "tinyint(1)") , both work for criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("vote" , Boolean.TRUE)) ; criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount()); , but not work for projectionlist.add(Projections.sum("vote") , "sum");

Comment: Finally , I decided to use HQL to solve this problem : https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=997522